# How to use renewed service certificate in Kestrel webserver

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

We are using Asp.Net core 2.1, Kestrel web server and service fabric. We have server certificate for our services which get bound to the service during service startup. The certificates are stored and renewed in Azure Key Vault.

The question is how can we bind the service to the renewed certificate without restarting or re-deploying the service at runtime?